# StateMachine и ожидание выполнения

Tags: java

Согласно ТЗ, мне необходимо реализовать управление движущимся объектом с периодическими паузами в 2 секунды между каждым выполняемым действием. При этом использовать wait() или sleep() не рекомендовано, предлагается применять конечный автомат.

За пару часов изысканий я не нашел подобных решений, и возник вопрос - правильно ли я вообще понял задание и есть ли такая возможность в state machine?

Если вопрос абсурдный - извиняюсь, ранее не использовал машину состояний.

Comment: Ну, состояние тут понятно зачем. Машина находится каждый раз в разном состоянии "Выполняется действие такое, выполняется такое, ожидает приказов и т.д." Одним из действий будет "ждать 2 секунды". Надо будет только кинуть ей список нужных действий и запустить